# T-SQL: "Must declare the scalar variable" while trying to save query's output to a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Sale table:

```
Product varchar(20),
Month varchar(20),
Value int
```

And here is what I'm trying to do:

```
declare @Result int
exec('SELECT @Result = SUM(Value) FROM Sale WHERE Product = ''' + @somevar + ''' AND Month = ''' + @othervar + ''' GROUP BY Product')
```

And this is what I get: `Must declare the scalar variable "@Result".`

Why is that so? I saw very similar code in some tutorial and it was obviously said to be working... I have no idea what is wrong here, please help.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL here?

Comment: Sorry, edited. See now please.

Comment: You still haven't demonstrated any particular need for dynamic SQL so the easiest answer will be to not use it. Do you actually have some reason that requires it?

Comment: Does it change anything if we remove that 'exec' part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that variables aren't in scope in the `EXEC`

You don't need your SQL injection prone dynamic SQL or `GROUP BY` though.

```
    SELECT @Result = SUM(Value)
    FROM   Sale
    WHERE  Product = @somevar
           AND Month = @othervar
```

If there *is* some legit reason why you need dynamic SQL then you should use `sp_executesql` and parameters.

```
DECLARE @Nsql   NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Result INT;

SET @Nsql = N'SELECT @Result = SUM(Value)
FROM   Sale
WHERE  Product = @somevar
       AND Month = @othervar'

EXEC sp_executesql
  @Nsql,
  N'@somevar VARCHAR(50), @othervar INT,@Result INT OUTPUT',
  @somevar= @somevar,
  @othervar=@othervar,
  @Result = @Result OUTPUT;
```

Comment: Huh. It's strange because I already tried something like that, but I thought that you cannot use variables in this way (it threw errors). Well, thank you, problem seems to be solved.