# Must declare variable

Tags: sql-server

I have an error during the execution of my proc that I must declare my variable while this last variable is well declared

because I declared my variables in the proc

Proc Syntax

```
USE [Test]
GO
 
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER   PROCEDURE [dbo].[ADMIN_D]  @LNK_Name nvarchar(60) ,@bdd  varchar(50) ,@PS VARCHAR(80), @SCH SYSNAME = 'dbo'
AS
 
 
    Declare @sqlm varchar(max)
    Declare @sql1 nvarchar(max)
    Declare @sql nvarchar(max)
    Declare @sqlZ varchar(max)
 
    Declare @LINK nvarchar(max)
    Declare @LINK1  nvarchar(max)
    Declare @LINK2  varchar(max)
    --Declare @bdd varchar(35)
    Declare @Login      varchar(80)
    Declare @Datetime   datetime
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
 
    IF (ORIGINAL_LOGIN() IN (''))
    BEGIN;
        PRINT 'Déploiement interdit - Contactez l''équipe SQL ';
        RETURN;
    END;
 
    SET @Datetime = Getdate()
    SET @Login = system_user
 
    SELECT @sql = Definition
    FROM sys.procedures p
        INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules m ON p.object_id = m.object_id
    where name = @PS and p.schema_id = SCHEMA_ID(@SCH)
 
    --BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRAN
 
    raiserror('--- Alim Z_CODESOURCE de Prod',0,1) WITH NOWAIT
    SET @sqlZ = 'EXEC dbo.Z_CODESOURCE_Alim @NOM_OBJET = ''' + @PS + ''''
        SET @LINK = N'EXEC (@sqlZ) AT ' + QUOTENAME(@LNK_Name);;
        EXEC sp_executesql @LINK;
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
 
 
    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM ADMIN_DEPLOY_BLOCK WHERE NOM_PS = @PS AND Nom_Schema = @SCH)
    BEGIN
        SELECT  'DEPLOIEMENT INTERDIT PAR ' + ACTEUR + '. RAISON: ' + RAISON
            FROM ADMIN_DEPLOY_BLOCK 
            WHERE NOM_PS = @PS
                AND Nom_Schema = @SCH;
 
        PRINT 'Pas de déploiement !'
    END 
    ELSE
        BEGIN TRY
 
                SET @sqlm = ' USE [' + @bdd + '];DELETE FROM METADATA WHERE NAME = '''+@PS+''''
                SET @LINK = N'EXEC (@sqlm) AT ' + QUOTENAME(@LNK_Name);
                                EXEC sp_executesql @LINK ;
 
 
                SET @sql1 = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type IN (''P'', ''FN'') AND name = '''+@PS+''' AND schema_id = ( select schema_id from sys.schemas WHERE name=''' + @SCH + ''' )) DROP PROCEDURE ' + @SCH +  '.' + @PS
                SET @sql1 = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type IN (''P'', ''FN'') AND name = '''+@PS+''') DROP PROCEDURE '+@PS
                SET @sql1 = REPLACE(@sql1,'''','''''')
                SET @sql1 = 'USE [' + @bdd + ']; EXEC(''' + @sql1 + ''')'
                SET @LINK1 = N'EXEC (@sql1) AT ' + QUOTENAME(@LNK_Name) ;
                                EXEC sp_executesql @LINK1 ;
 
 
                SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql,'''','''''')
                SET @sql = 'USE [' + @bdd + ']; EXEC(''' + @sql + ''')'
                SET @LINK2 = N'EXEC (@sql) AT ' + QUOTENAME(@LNK_Name) ;
                                EXEC sp_executesql @LINK2 ;
 
                INSERT INTO LOG_DEPLOYPS (LOGIN, PS, DAT) values (@login, @PS, @datetime)
 
                Print ''
                Print ''
                Print 'Déploiement effectuée avec succès'
                --COMMIT TRAN
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
                Print ''
                Print ''
            Print 'Une erreur est survenue: ' + CAST(@@ERROR AS VARCHAR(255))
 
            SELECT
            @PS AS ProcedureName
            ,ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
            ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
            ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
            ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
            ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
            ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
 
            --ROLLBACK TRAN
 
        END CATCH
 
END
```

Execute Proc

```
 USE [Test]
GO
DECLARE @return_value int
 
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[ADMIN_D]
        @bdd = N'PROD',
        @PS = N'SP_login',
        @LNK_Name=N'uat-link'
 
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

Someone who can help me please

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D1nU.png)

[Run stored procedure on linked server (linked server name as variable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55004758/run-stored-procedure-on-linked-server-linked-server-name-as-variable)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `SET @LINK = N'EXEC (@sqlZ) AT ' + QUOTENAME(@LNK_Name);; EXEC sp_executesql @LINK;` The variable `@sqlZ` is *not* defined in your dynamic statement. Presumably you should be passing it as a parameter to `sp_executesql`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [T-SQL: "Must declare the scalar variable" while trying to save query's output to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27471768/t-sql-must-declare-the-scalar-variable-while-trying-to-save-querys-output-to)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is these lines (and other places later on where you use the same pattern):

```
SET @LINK = N'EXEC (@sqlZ) AT ' + QUOTENAME(@LNK_Name);;
EXEC sp_executesql @LINK;
```

The `sp_executesql` function creates a new execution context that doesn't know about the `@sqlZ` variable. To get around this, there are additional arguments you must pass to the function to set up the variables and their values.